# 1 hour 10 minute layover in Addis Ababa?

Tags: airports, addis-ababa

I am looking at going through Addis Ababa on my way to Cape Town. It seems that this should be enough time and that I didn't have to go through immigration until I get to South Africa- is this still the case?

Also, I assume it is, but is this airport safe for a young woman traveling alone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's plenty of time.  The airport is not large, and transit passengers do not need to clear immigration.

The airport seemed quite safe to me when I was there.  It was fairly busy, so you will never be alone.  I am not a woman, however, so my experience isn't 100% relevant.

Bring warm clothing.  I was traveling in the summer, so I didn't have enough of that, and the elevation is quite high, so temperatures are low.  The terminal is not heated, and it is open to the outside.

Comment: Thanks so much. That's what I figured, but I really appreciate the confirmation. Nice tip about the terminal being open air.